# How to prevent joining values in Row Group (column) of Crosstab?

Tags: jasper-reports, crosstab

Is there a way to unmerge cells with the same value in crosstab?

The problem is that same valued cells are getting merged.

I want the value to be repeated and have cell borders. For example, in a row group, if i have 2 columns, col1 with values 'abc' and col2 with values 1,2,3 and if there are 3 rows, the col1 is one big cell with 'abc' printed only once.

This is what I don't want and instead want it to be printed 3 times.

This is presentation I required:

[image]

Currently I have:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4_1" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="a53b72b8-0dda-468b-bffd-3e28d792a2d6">
    <style name="Crosstab_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CG" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CT" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#005FB3">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select * from test]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="col1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="col2" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="col3" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="col4" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="col5" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <summary>
        <band height="214" splitType="Stretch">
            <crosstab>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="214" uuid="a8663f8c-217c-4ef3-ab2c-a11120aea80e"/>
                <rowGroup name="col11" width="60">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{col1}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabRowHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="6e0cb2ba-ea94-4b5e-a774-3092f6b0bd06"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col11}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabRowHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                        <cellContents>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="-2147483648" height="-2147483648" uuid="4787314d-3cb1-4f29-99d4-1443453e5d1b"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Total col11]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                </rowGroup>
                <rowGroup name="col21" width="60">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.Integer">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{col2}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabRowHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="bf3d5e77-12a9-44cc-94d1-3f2a317f32d1"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col21}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabRowHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                        <cellContents>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="-2147483648" height="-2147483648" uuid="c21bf242-edbb-4533-9d7d-7120282703a5"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Total col21]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                </rowGroup>
                <columnGroup name="col31" height="20">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{col3}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="120" height="20" uuid="320dded3-882b-4e8d-a821-ce94996a72d2">
                                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                                </reportElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col31}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabColumnHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="-2147483648" height="-2147483648" uuid="e78a53ad-4437-41d1-8cea-ab1a2fdf09d3"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Total col31]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                </columnGroup>
                <measure name="col4_MEASURE1" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Count">
                    <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{col4}]]></measureExpression>
                </measure>
                <measure name="col5_MEASURE1" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Count">
                    <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{col5}]]></measureExpression>
                </measure>
                <crosstabCell width="120" height="20">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CD">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="ddc2801e-7492-4848-b7f7-422d7267cadb"/>
                            <box>
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            </box>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col4_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="60" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="38136ac4-94aa-46ef-91ca-b32ac1d19aba">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                            </reportElement>
                            <box>
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            </box>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col5_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" columnTotalGroup="col31">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="0b620468-123a-434e-8a87-be8125b86470"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col4_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="d3c3da1b-7c66-48e5-8328-9c775e036229"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col5_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="col11">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="08db97ef-0f91-4301-a552-2eec171c2b91"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col4_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="2fa36822-c633-4954-b6ad-bb2633dd827b"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col5_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="col11" columnTotalGroup="col31">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="a1545b3f-ac13-4e97-8720-3b526af18207"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col4_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="02c1d1d7-8b20-461e-8bd9-b2e4ceff02ed"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col5_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="col21">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CG">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="10" uuid="94b61c57-3b18-4134-a48f-36394cf8ac28"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col4_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="60" height="10" uuid="b8b84ab6-a800-427e-8738-40dc17f8b7ae"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col5_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="col21" columnTotalGroup="col31">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="e34172fb-29af-43aa-af6b-50bb63949236"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col4_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="60" height="10" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="232ba479-f365-4fb8-8402-4a9d50f79c6c"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col5_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
            </crosstab>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Hi Alex, I surely have to use crosstabs for my requirement. The problem is same valued cells are getting merged . I want the value to be repeated and have cell borders. For ex, in a row group, if i have 2 columns, col1 with values 'abc' and col2 with values 1,2,3 and if there are 3 rows, the col1 is one big cell with 'abc' printed only once. This is what I don't want and instead want it to be printed 3 times. I am unable to paste any picture, as this editor is not giving me any provision to do so

Comment: Hi, I have uploaded pictures in the mentioned links below. The one that says not suitable crosstab is what Jasper is giving me, what I want is the picture named 'required crosstab' . http://tinypic.com/m/jjy5qc/1    ,      http://tinypic.com/m/jjy5qd/1

Comment: Also, many jasper tutorials say, there is a check box where if I check it, the merge cells appear else its shown as unmerged . I could not find it in the design editor, would you please let me know where is it available in the design layout of jasper?

Comment: Alex, I have put the jrxml in the question. Please do have a look at it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ***col1*** and ***col2*** in your sample are **Rows Groups**. This name (*Row Group*) tell us that *JasperReports* engine unions all *non unique* values in groups in case using *Crosstab* component. That is why values should be always ordered for grouping data right (as shown at image below).

[image: The property of Row Group]

The data in *Row Groups* will be grouped by *JR* engine and *one group is drawing as one cell*.

*`Does this mean that the problem has no solution?`* - No. Let's solve it!

Looks like you want "to join" *col1* and *col2* columns values. This means that the value of *col1 Row Group* can be added to the "column" of *col2 Row Group*.

### Example

#### Datasource

It is enough to test sample with simple *csv* datasource.

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
abcd,1,b,1c,434
abcd,2,c,2c,333
abcd,3,c,4c,333
abcd,3,c,4c,333
abcd,5,c,4c,333
abcd,3,e,3g,909
```

The name of data adapter for this datasource in the example below is *values.csv*. The first line from the file is skipped - it is contains the column's name.

#### Report template

We should set the width of first column (*col1 Row Group*) as zero and increase the width of second column (*col2 Row Group*) to place additionally value of *col1*. In this case the *JR engine* draws both both values for each unique *col2* value. We still need the first column because we need value of *col1* (the bucket for *col1 Row Group*).

The design in *Jaspersoft Studio* (*JSS*) looks like:

[image: Report design]

The *jrxml* file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Crosstab. Merged values" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="values.csv"/>
    <style name="Crosstab_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <field name="col1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="col2" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="col3" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="col4" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="col5" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <summary>
        <band height="214" splitType="Stretch">
            <crosstab>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="214"/>
                <crosstabHeaderCell>
                    <cellContents style="Crosstab_CH">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20"/>
                            <box>
                                <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <text><![CDATA[Col1]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="60" y="0" width="60" height="20"/>
                            <box>
                                <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <text><![CDATA[Col2]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabHeaderCell>
                <rowGroup name="col11" width="0">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{col1}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabRowHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH"/>
                    </crosstabRowHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                        <cellContents/>
                    </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                </rowGroup>
                <rowGroup name="col21" width="120">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.Integer">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{col2}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabRowHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CD">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20"/>
                                <box>
                                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                </box>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col11}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="60" y="0" width="60" height="20"/>
                                <box>
                                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                </box>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col21}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabRowHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                        <cellContents/>
                    </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                </rowGroup>
                <columnGroup name="col31" height="20">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{col3}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="120" height="20"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col31}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabColumnHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents/>
                    </crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                </columnGroup>
                <measure name="col4_MEASURE1" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Count">
                    <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{col4}]]></measureExpression>
                </measure>
                <measure name="col5_MEASURE1" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Count">
                    <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{col5}]]></measureExpression>
                </measure>
                <crosstabCell width="120" height="20">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CD">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20"/>
                            <box>
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            </box>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col4_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="60" y="0" width="60" height="20"/>
                            <box>
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            </box>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{col5_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
            </crosstab>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

#### Output result

The result in *JSS*:

[image: The generated result in JSS]

Comment: Thanks a lot !! The solution worked like a charm !! However, I have one problem now, when I moved col1 RowGroup details to col2 RowGroup, and previously if I had a expression on col1, say dateutils.addminutes($F{col1},24), I am unable to do the same when I copy paste col1 into col2. How do I solve this? (col1 for the sake of explaining I have assumed it as a date field). I am unable to use $F fields on the moved columns

Comment: You are welcome :)  But you can use `$V{col11}` - the bucket for `$F{col1}` (`<bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{col2}]]></bucketExpression>` - from the `<rowGroup name="col11" width="0">`)

Comment: Yes the answer was of superb help !! Thanks again !!